# Extract datapoints of a plot from an .eps file

Tags: figure, eps

I have a .eps file which contains a plot with several curves

[image]

The .eps file's contents is huge and cannot be entirely put here, but I need to extract these datapoints somehow. Is there any package, toolkit, or whatever  that can help me out?

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help without a lot more information. Firstly; PostScript is a programming language, so (potentially) the only way to extract any information is going to be to run a PostScript interpreter on the program. Secondly you haven't really explained what you mean by 'extract those data points' All you are going to get out of the EPS (at best) is a position in the document of where the 'data point' is drawn. There certainly isn't anything which is going to do this for you directly from the EPS. You could try rendering it to an image, might be more tools for that.